# Change button's color Extjs 3.4

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I have a button, with a `cls : 'pdf'`. All I want is changing the Background-color (and then make it bigger than the scale : 'large' if possible?)
I tried :

```
.pdf
{
background-image:none !important;
background-color:#00cc99 !important;
}

.pdf div a span
{
color: black !important;
}

.pdf .x-btn-inner
{
color: black !important;
 background-image: none !important;
 border-color: black !important;
 border-top-color: black !important;
}

.pdf
{
background-color : black !important;
}
```

But nothing workd. I read it's possible to change it with modify the gif buttons, but is there another way, using the css only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution with :

```
.pdf  .x-btn-mc
{
background-image : none !important;
background-color : #00cc99 !important;
}
```

I guess the '`.x-btn-mc`' is specific to extjs 3.4

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
.pdf .x-btn-button .x-btn-inner {
  background-color: #00cc99;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything, even with '!important'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a right answer how to change button's color:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?21904-Button-color&p=388267&viewfull=1#post388267

```
.pdf .x-btn-tl, .pdf .x-btn-tr, .pdf .x-btn-tc, .pdf .x-btn-ml, 
.pdf .x-btn-mr, .pdf .x-btn-mc, .pdf .x-btn-bl, .pdf .x-btn-br, .pdf .x-btn-bc{
    background-image : none !important;
    background-color : #00cc99 !important;
}
```